# copy directories from list of directories in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, directory, copy, subdirectory

I have a list of subdirectories within a directory (a text file, e.g., `directories_subset.txt`) that I want to copy, rather than move, (including all of their contents) to another directory. The list specifies full paths, with each subdirectory on a new line and ending with `/`.

I've tried:
`cat directories_subset.txt | while read line; do cp "$line" /Volumes/Toshiba/Bird_UCE_project/raxml_genetrees/raxml_bestML_genetree/directories_subset; done` but this only produces `is a directory (not copied)` messages.

Comment: There are several ways you can do this. Powershell, windows batch, C# etc.. To be able to help you though, you will need to provide more details. Check out how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm looking to do this in Mac OSX Terminal. Not sure a cp command would work, e.g., `cp directories_subset.txt directories_subset/` would just copy the text file to that directory.

Comment: Not sure what other details you need

Comment: Did you read the "How to Ask" article? Stack overflow is more for specific errors. Since you haven't tried anything, we won't be able to help out. I personally don't know Mac OSX but someone with that knowledge may find this question and will be able to help out. To make your question more visible to those with Mac OSX knowledge, add Mac OSX as a tag.

Comment: edited with more info and one attempt I've made at this

Answer (score 0):

While I merely wanted to copy rather than move these subdirectories, I used `cat directories_subset.txt | while read line; do mv "$line" /Volumes/Toshiba/Bird_UCE_project/raxml_genetrees/raxml_bestML_genetree/directories_subset; done` to move a subset of the directories to a new directory. I then went to the new directory, selected all subdirectories, copied, and pasted back into their original parent directory.

I'm sure a more streamlined approach could be done, but I'm too pressed for time and this was the fastest option I could think of.